# How to change DrawersKit, so that it will appear from Beginning

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigation-drawer

I Use the DrawersKit from BabylonPartners from Github for my own Project. It should appear from the beginning and not until you press the button. In addition, it should not disappear completely when you pull it down are just like the Apple Maps App or Facebook Local only smaller. Standard should be that it opens to the center of the display and then either reduced or enlarged. Have tried so much but it did not work out.

Here is the Github project: https://github.com/Babylonpartners/DrawerKit
and a screenshot from my project right now

[image]